# How to debug in rails server console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails, I want to debug my rails application through debugger i rails server console.So please tell me shortcuts and there meaning so that I can be able to debug.

Comment: Do you want to debug it from `rails console` or you want to pause the code at some point and debug it like developers usually do in development ?

Comment: @dkp I want to pause the code and debug it.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote

Comment: Which version of Rails?

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the `rails console` in production, you can type:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c`

Or, if you want to debug code during runtime, you can use:

[**pry-remote**](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 contains by default `byebug` and `web-console`. In development mode you can simply call `byebug` anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console.

In views you can use:

```
<%= console %>
```

to access an IRB console on exception pages.

See [debugging guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html).

If you don't have Rails 4, add to your `Gemfile` following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

and run `bundle install`.

Answer (score -1):

The official way to do this is using the `byebug` gem. Install it by executing

```
gem install byebug
```

After that you can put a `byebug` statement anywhere in your code:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def new
    byebug
    @person = Person.new
  end
end
```

As soon as the application reaches this statement, it stops and presents a command prompt in the shell you started the server process.

See the [RoR Debugging Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem) for further details.